# Can't find some icons in jekyll theme site files

Tags: html, css, web, markdown, jekyll

I am building a site from a jekyll theme. I was able to completely customize the whole site except the yellow icons in the picture. These weren't found in the site files. Nowhere. Inspecting that element just shows a div class. I need to remove these but I can't because I can't find them anywhere.

[image: Screenshot of the page]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons are actually font. To remove them you will have to remove specific classes from the element. In this case for example if you want to remove Laptop icon, you would remove `fa-laptop` class from the `i` element.

You can read more about it on the following link [Font awesome - Get started](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you search for a file called **font-awesome.min.css** in your project root directory? These icons should be a reference from that file. You can modify the mappings to point to something else.

Comment: Thank you to both of you! This was really helpful.@MarioNikolaus @AbhimanyuShekhawat